# How to redirect an anonymous user until he gets the captcha right

Tags: django

How can I force the an anonymous user to stay in a page by always redirecting him back to it until he gets the captcha in there right? To handle the captcha form I can use [django simple captcha](https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-captcha/), my problem is in how to know if the captcha was solved and if not how I could redirect him.

confirmation.html

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Captcha test.</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField


class ConfirmationForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
    class Meta():
        fields = ['captcha']

    def save(self):
        # some type of anonymous user confirmation variable that I could set to true to stop redirecting the user
        anonymous.human = True
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from home.views import Confirmation, Home


urlpatterns = [
    path('', Confirmation, name='confirmation'),
    path('', Home, name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
def Confirmation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if anonymous.human == True:
            return redirect('home')
        if anonymous.human == False:
            return redirect('confirmation')
    else:
        form = ConfirmationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'base/confirmation.html', context)



def Home(request):
    if human == False:
        return redirect('confirmation')

    context = {
        ...
    }

    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can know if `captcha` is right [by validating the form](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#validate-the-form):

```
def confirmation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfirmationForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['is_human'] = True
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = ConfirmationForm()

    return render(request, 'base/confirmation.html', {'form': form})


def home(request):
    if request.session.get('is_human'):
        print('User is human')

    return render(request, 'base/home.html', {})
```

If captcha does not match then the view will `return render(request, 'base/confirmation.html', context)` and render the form errors.

Comment: Yes, the form validation logic works but anonymous.human does not exist, I still need to add human to anonymous user and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, `anonymous.human` was part of your code, so I just left where it was. Django [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/) offers full support for anonymous sessions, that is where you can store your variable.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just remember to explain your issue overall next time to avoid this kind of situation :)